# Categories showing page not found

Tags: categories, permalinks

I recently changed my permalink to /%postname%/ instead of /%categoryname%//%postname%/. However, as soon as I made that change, the category on the sidebar stopped working and displays page not found for each of my categories. I cannot provide a URL right no since I have changed the format back to /%categoryname%//%postname%/ to avoid 404 errors.
Please help me out.
Thanks!

Comment: It really depends on how the categories are being listed in the sidebar. If you have, say, a menu with pasted-in absolute URLs to each category, then it won't be updated. If your theme has hard-coded links, those won't be updated. Look through your theme and find out how the menu in question is created - if it's a dynamic sidebar, look in wp-admin at what widget it's using - to find out how it's building the menu. If it seems to be set to pull categories dynamically, you may have an issue with caching.